# Excel or Rails, Capitalize first letter, change all caps to capitalized, but respect capitalization mid name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

Given names like below:

**richard should be Richard**

**RICHARD should be Richard**

**richAnne should be RichAnne**

I'd rather this be done in excel, but my other option is using Rails.

Comment: So if you have just one capital letter in the middle of a name, it's probably correct? And you just have forenames, not forenames plus surnames? If you had RICHANNE you would be stuck?

Comment: What sort of data are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_string = string.slice(0,1).capitalize + string.slice(1..-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your examples.

```
words = ['richard', 'RICHARD', 'richAnne']
=> ["richard", "RICHARD", "richAnne"]

words.map{|w| w.titleize.gsub(' ','')}
=> ["Richard", "Richard", "RichAnne"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can do:

```
>> 'richard'.titleize.split.join
=> "Richard"
>> 'RICHARD'.titleize.split.join
=> "Richard"
>> 'richAnne'.titleize.split.join
=> "RichAnne"
```

The `.split.join` is not necessary for the first two cases, but it is for the last.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison, in Excel you could try this

```
=IF(SUM((CODE(MID(A1&REPT(" ",10),COLUMN(A:J),1))>=65)*(CODE(MID(A1&REPT(" ",10),COLUMN(A:J),1))<=90))=LEN(A1),PROPER(A1),UPPER(LEFT(A1))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

which counts the number of capital letters in the name, but it looks very messy compared to the Ruby solutions. Change to suit the longest name you expect.

It's an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could also do it by checking to see if there were *any* lower case letters in the name and if so, just capitalise the first letter.

```
=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(MID("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",COLUMN(A:Z),1),A1))),UPPER(LEFT(A1))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),PROPER(A1))
```

A pattern-matching solution would be neater but would need VBA.

[image]